# Plotting horizontal line on Manipulate Plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I have the following code, which outputs a `Manipulate` style plot. I want to draw a horizontal line on the plot related to `q`, with equation: `y = Roche[ρ]`.

My code is as follows:

```
Constants

au = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], "Meters"]]; 
c = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "MetersPerSecond"]]; 
Qpr = 1; 
Lsun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarLuminosity"], "Watts"]]; 
Rsun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"], "Meters"]]; 
Msun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarMass"], "Kilograms"]]; 
G = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "GravitationalConstant"], ("Meters"^2*"Newtons")/"Kilograms"^2]]; 
year = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"]]; 
Myr = year*10^6; 
Gyr = year*10^9; 
Mwd = 0.6*Msun; 
Cst = 1.27; 
U = 1*10^17; 

Functions

L[t_] := (3.26*Lsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun)))/(0.1 + t/Myr)^1.18; 
Roche[dens_] := (0.65*Cst*Rsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun))^(1/3))/(dens/3000)^3^(-1); 
Papsis[t_] := a[t]*(1 - e[t]); 

Radiative Drag

RDdadtR\[Rho]a = -((3*L[t]*Qpr*(2 + 3*e[t]^2))/(c^2*(16*Pi*2000*Rast*a[t]*(1 - e[t]^2)^(3/2)))); 
RDdedtR\[Rho]a = -((15*L[t]*e[t])/(c^2*(32*Pi*Rast*2000*a[t]^2*Sqrt[1 - e[t]^2]))); 

Null

RDsolR\[Rho]a = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][a][t] == RDdadtR\[Rho]a, Derivative[1][e][t] == RDdedtR\[Rho]a, a[0] == a0, e[0] == 3/10}, {a, e}, {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
    {Rast, \[Rho], a0}]; 

fRDticks = {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1/Myr}], Automatic}}; 

Manipulate[Column[{Style["Working Plot", Bold], Plot[fun[func, t]/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}], Style["Compiled Plot", Bold], 
    If[comp === {}, Plot[fun[func, t]/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}], 
     Plot[comp, {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}]]}], {{func, 1}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "q"}}, 
  {{Rast, 0.005}, 0.0001, 0.1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Rho], 3000}, 1000, 7000, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{a0, 10, "a0 (au)"}, 2, 20, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Button["Append", AppendTo[comp, fun[func, t]]], Button["Reset", comp = {}], 
  TrackedSymbols -> {func, Rast, \[Rho], a0}, Initialization :> {comp = {}, fun[sel_, t_] := Switch[sel, 1, RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[1]][t], 2, 
      RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[2]][t], 3, RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[1]][t]*(1 - RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[2]][t])], 
    scale[sel_] := Switch[sel, 1 | 3, au, 2, 1]}]
```

I have tried to use `Epilog` but no line was displayed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Plot[{f[x],1},{x,0,1}]`will plot a line at y=1.

Comment: @A.G. I'm not sure how to integrate that into my current code.

Comment: Use `InfiniteLine[]` or the `GridLines` option of `Plot[]`.

Comment: @testing09 when computing Roche[3000] (where 3000 is the starting value of \[Rho], I obtain 5.7 x 10^8. This is completely out of the range of the plot... So this horizontal line may be drawn but will not be visible. Other than that, Epilog works just fine.

Comment: @DenisCousineau Oh i tried Epilog- it will be in range when the a0 slider is reduced to close to its minimum value. How did you write the `Epilog` statement if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @testing09 something along the lines of `Plot[{fun[func, t]/scale[func], Roche[\[Rho]]} ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Epilog can be added with

```
Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, 
      InfiniteLine[{{0, Roche[\[Rho]]}, {10, Roche[\[Rho]]}}]
}
```

inside your Plot command(s), as in for example

```
Manipulate[Column[{
   Style["Working Plot", Bold], 
   Plot[fun[func, t]/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
    FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, 
      InfiniteLine[{{0, Roche[\[Rho]]}, {10, Roche[\[Rho]]}}]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}], 
   Style["Compiled Plot", Bold], 
   If[comp === {}, 
    Plot[fun[func, t]/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
     FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}], 
    Plot[comp, {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}]]
   }], {{func, 1}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "q"}}, {{Rast, 0.005}, 
  0.0001, 0.1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Rho], 3000}, 1000,
   7000, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a0, 10, "a0 (au)"}, 2, 20, 
  0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Button["Append", AppendTo[comp, fun[func, t]]], 
 Button["Reset", comp = {}], 
 TrackedSymbols -> {func, Rast, \[Rho], a0}, 
 Initialization :> {comp = {}, 
   fun[sel_, t_] := 
    Switch[sel, 1, RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[1]][t], 2, 
     RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[2]][t], 3, 
     RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[1]][
       t]*(1 - RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[2]][t])], 
   scale[sel_] := Switch[sel, 1 | 3, au, 2, 1]}]
```

However, I can't see the line as it seems to be out of range all the time.

Comment: Thanks! The reason is that Roche[\rho] is about three orders of magnitude smaller than the other values, so it does show, but Is really close to zero. I still need to play around with the other variable values so the correct plot is visible.